# What is the fastest performing way in PHP to check a lot of remote files for a certain text?

Tags: php, file, stream

I want to check a list of ~300k webpages if they contain a certain text (e.g. "not available"). This should be done every day.

What would be the best way to do this in PHP?

I can use fread&fopen to read the page line by line, and if a line contains the text, go to the next url.

An other option is to use cURL, which is suppose to be faster than fread, but I'm not sure if it is possible to open a stream and read the page line by line, or that I have to download the whole file and then check it for the text.

Are there other (better) options?

What will perform best on speed?

Comment: I am just now reading about simultaneuos http requests in curl: http://www.phpied.com/simultaneuos-http-requests-in-php-with-curl/. Will this be a good performing option?

Comment: For something like this... I'm tempted to say that you're going about your business the wrong way. Why should you scrape 300k pages for a string on a daily basis anyway? how about scraping them, storing hashes of the contents, then check the hashes that have changed and rescan only those pages. Just saying...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I have no way of knowing if a page has been changed. I'd love to use a more efficient method, but am not seeing in how doing something you suggest in this case. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Well, using [the `Last-Modified` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) for one, then instead of searching the contents of the entire page, just read in the file once, and store the `sha1($contents);` checksum, next time around: if the stored checksum is the same as the one of the content you fetched, you can safely assume the contents hasn't changed. That saves you a lot of trouble checking contents you've already processed

Comment: For future visitors: I'm using the https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle lib now, which support asynchronous requests. Should be the fastest solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have a script that does the similar thing as you mentioned, i found fread more reliable and faster than curl process, especially if the page has media in it. I would recommend fread.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. From your experience, do you have any other recommendations?

Comment: my best bet is try both and calculate the time too see which one is faster, on the other note , what exactly are you trying to do? i mean what is this program for? i am asking because there may be other ways of doing this?